# Creating a tuple from two lists of two different types

Tags: recursion, f#, tuples

I'm trying to create a list of tuples from two different lists where each head from the two lists will become a tuple(ex: headList1 and headList2 become a tuple), and this continues for each element) and I'm getting type errors in F# and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I tried taking away the parentheses putting in braces etc and still to no avail.

```
let rec pairToTuple letter count = // assume that each list is the same, will return a list with (letter, count) in itself
  match letter with
  | [] -> [()]
  | e1::rest1, e2::rest2 -> let tup = (e1, e2) 
                            tup::(pairToTuple rest1 rest2 )
```

ex: (a,b,c) and (10,20,30) would become [ (a,10);(b,20);(c,30) ]

```
/home/codio/workspace/program/Program.fs(180,5): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type    ''a list'    but here has type    ''b * 'c'
[/home/codio/workspace/program/program.fsproj]
```

Comment: In your pattern match, the first pattern tries to match a single empty list []. The second pattern tries to match two lists e1::rest1, e2:rest2. All the patterns must be for the same data type.

Comment: Your second pattern returns a list of tuples. Your first pattern returns a list with a single null value. Your first pattern should just return an empty list [].

Answer (score 2):

What about List.zip function?

```
> List.zip ["a"; "b"; "c"; "d"] [1; 2; 3; 4];;
val it : (string * int) list = [("a", 1); ("b", 2); ("c", 3); ("d", 4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use the `List.map2` [function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.map2%5B't1,'t2,'u%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D):

```
let pairToTuple letterList countList =
    List.map2 (fun letter count -> (letter, count)) letterList countList
```

Or you can write it shorter in F# idioms:

```
let pairToTuple = List.map2 (fun letter count -> (letter, count))
```

If your question is an exercise and you don't want to use `List.map2`, then:

```
let rec pairToTuple letterList countList =
    match letterList, countList with
    | [], _ -> []
    | _, [] -> []
    | letter :: res1, count :: res2 ->
        (letter, count) :: pairToTuple res1 res2
```